# Is the timelike free boson CFT a valid CFT as per Segal's functorial CFT prescription?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Is the timelike free boson CFT a valid CFT as per Segal's functorial CFT prescription?

I am aware that the Euclidean free boson theory is a well-defined CFT, but I was wondering whether one might run into problems when trying to place the timelike free boson CFT into Segal's FQFT framework since the spectrum of the timelike free boson theory is unbounded from below.

Comment: Having a spectrum not bounded from below is not necessarily fatal: what matters is that it is bounded from below in any OPE, which is the case in the free boson CFT due to momentum conservation. This said, I know nothing about Segal's FQFT.